# Alternative to LOOKUPVALUE function for use within a measure?

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a measure that successfully calculates a cumulative amount of planned revenue through each month:

```
Revised Revenue :=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( Rev_Revised[Revenue] ),
    Data_Types[Data Types] = "Projected"
)
```

```
Cumulative Revised Revenue :=
IF (
    MIN ( MonthDate[MonthDate] )
        <= CALCULATE ( MAX ( Rev_Revised[MonthDate] ), ALL ( Rev_Revised ) ),
    CALCULATE (
        [Revised Revenue],
        FILTER (
            ALL ( MonthDate[MonthDate] ),
            MonthDate[MonthDate] <= MAX ( MonthDate[MonthDate] )
        )
    )
)
```

When used in a pivot table in conjunction with Running Total In..., it looks like this:

[image: image 1]

What I need to do now is create a new measure that multiplies a Revenue Capture % to each monthly cumulative amount (this is like a prediction on the lag of actually collecting the revenue), and those percentages are found in a related table:

[image: image 2]

Using `LOOKUPVALUE` in a measure obviously throws an error because it doesn't result in one value.  I could easily just create my own additional row under the pivot table that performs this calculation, but I'd really like it to be performed within the data model.  Any ideas?

Edit:
The closest solution I can come to now is a calculated column in my spend plan dataset that looks up the % for each row:

```
Monthly Rev Capture :=
LOOKUPVALUE (
    Rev_Capture[Revenue Capture],
    Rev_Capture[MonthDate], Rev_Revised[MonthDate]
)
```

And then a measure of this:

```
Rev Capture Amount :=
[Cumulative Revised Revenue] * AVERAGE ( Rev_Revised[Monthly Rev Capture] )
```

But that doesn't calculate correctly in the pivot table.  Here's what it looks like, also with the correct manual calculations displayed below the table for validation:

[image]

What I need is a measure similar to one of these, but of course these fail:

```
Rev Capture Total:=
[Cumulative Revised Revenue]*RELATED(Rev_Capture[Revenue Capture])
```

```
Rev Capture Total v2:=
     [Cumulative Revised Revenue]*LOOKUPVALUE(Rev_Capture[Revenue Capture],
MonthDate[MonthDate],
Rev_Capture[MonthDate])
```

Comment: Why are there multiple values? Are you grouping over multiple years for the same month?

Comment: Eventually we will, but those columns are mainly there because the 3 digit "Month" is present in a lot of sources, so we created relationships for those.  However, since that's not actually a date, and there are times when we need date context in calculations (like the running total example), we had to add that detail.  Not sure if that was the question you were asking or not.

Comment: Added an attempt at solving to the OP.

Comment: The lookup seems fine. I think your issue is somewhere else, possibly in the relationships?

Comment: The lookup is fine in a column, but I want it in a measure.  I guess I'm not explaining my situation correctly.  The problem with that approach is it's applying the % to the revenue in one month.  I need to apply it to the cumulative through each of those months.  I can't paste the entire table here; it's huge; has tons of detail/rows for each month that gets aggregated into one total revenue for a month.

Comment: I'll also add that date formatting in PowerPivot is extremely limited.  There's not a way to format 2/1/2020 into just FEB, or FEB 20, or something very simple/abbreviated for use in charts and tables.  That has added layers of complication and workarounds to a lot of my data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your v2 measure looks close but since it's not a calculated column, you can't just reference a column without using an aggregating function like `AVERAGE` or `MAX` or `VALUES` since the lookup function requires a single value to look up.

Try it like this:

```
Rev Capture Total v2 :=
[Cumulative Revised Revenue]
    * LOOKUPVALUE (
        Rev_Capture[Monthly Rev Capture],
        Rev_Capture[MonthDate], SELECTEDVALUE ( MonthDate[MonthDate] )
    )
```

If your filter context has a single month, `SELECTEDVALUE` will return the same as other aggregators like `SUM`/`MAX`/`AVERAGE`/`VALUES` but will return a blank if there are multiple values in the filter context since there's not just one option.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds close, but I don't see ```SELECTEDVALUE``` as an available function.  I tried ```VALUES``` there, but then I get an error when adding to pivot table "a table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected."

Comment: `SELECTEDVALUE` is a newer DAX function that's a shortcut for `IF(HASONEVALUE(X), VALUES(X))`. I'd expect that error for a row total where there are indeed multiple months in the filter context with just `VALUES`.

Comment: I'm at the point where I can get the correct amounts now if I use MonthDate in my pivot table, but doesn't work with Month.  So, I probably do have some relationship issues to work through.  Thanks for your input.  I'll mark as solved.